# Changing Character base on the given integer?

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the given integer to a character

for example:

```
N = 5;
result = +-+-+;
```

Right now I am having a hard time implementing this

What I have tried so far is this

```
    public void Main()
    {
        int integer;

        Console.WriteLine("How many strings : ");
        integer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



        ChangeCharacter(integer);
    }

    public void ChangeCharacter(int A)
    {
        string p = "+";
        string m = "-";
        Console.WriteLine("Printing : " + A + " strings");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < A ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p,m);
        }
    }
```

the result is only : + + + + + it is not including the - sign

I am just new to c# and I am taking a coding exam to build my logic more . Sorry for my bad english because it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: What do you think `Console.WriteLine(p, m)` does? I guarantee it's [not what you think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_).

Comment: @John I tried separting the 2 variable sir but it gives me 10 set of "+-" strings

Comment: What is the exact result you expect from entering 5? At the moment I would expect `A` lines of `p`, but that differs from the first half of your question.

Comment: In terms of logic, if you would like to generate a sequence of alternating between `+` and `-`, you need a condition to specify which character you would like to print at each position. Can you continue from here?

Comment: What i tried again is the odd and even setup sir now i get the result

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(p,m)` the correct is `Console.WriteLine("{0}",m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct  like this :

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < A ; i++)
    { 
        if(i%2==0)
           Console.Write("+");
        else
           Console.Write("-");

    }
```

Comment: Thank you I also did it like this

Comment: but is there any other way to write this code beatifully?

Comment: @BoonMingProg `Console.Write(i  % 2 == 0 ? "+" : "-");` but remember that shorter isn't always better. Readable/maintainable code is more important than short code. By the way, don't forget to accept vahab's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a one-liner, LINQ would do the job as well:

```cs
int n = 5; // Expect: +-+-+

Console.WriteLine(new string(Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => x % 2 == 0 ? '+' : '-').ToArray()));
```

Explanation

```cs
new string(
  Enumerable.Range(0, n) // Generate n integers start from 0
    .Select(x =>         // for each integer,
      x % 2 == 0         // if it's even
      ? '+'              // return +
      : '-'              // otherwise -
    ).ToArray()          // convert selected characters into character array
  )
);
```